# 503 Error while trying to send SMS with Twilio

Tags: php, twilio

I´m using Twilio PHP API to send mass sms to my customers.
Problem is that i can only send like 80st SMS and then i got a server error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
>   (Backend fetch failed)

Well i think this might be the error.
Because i get no success echo `echo "Sent message to $name` and in the twilio SMS log i can only see that 80 SMS of 200 has been sent.

What can cause this error?

```
foreach ($usrs as $number => $name) {
    try{
        $sms = $client->account->messages->create(

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            $number,

            array(
                // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
                'from' => "xxxxxxxxxxx", 

                // the sms body
                'body' => "Hey $name. $text"
            )
        );

        // Display a confirmation message on the screen
        echo "Sent message to $name <br>";
    } 
    catch (TwilioException $e) {
        die( $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: i think its because you can send specific message per second. 
put some delay after some sms and [check link](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio has a limit of 100 concurrent API requests and will only send 1 message a second](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues). As Ahmed suggested in the comments, I recommend you add a delay between calls to the API if you are sending more than 100 messages.

**edit**

Adds `sleep(1)` for each message. This will make the page delay a second after sending each message.

```
foreach ($usrs as $number => $name) {
    try{
        $sms = $client->account->messages->create(

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            $number,

            array(
                // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
                'from' => "xxxxxxxxxxx", 

                // the sms body
                'body' => "Hey $name. $text"
            )
        );

        // Display a confirmation message on the screen
        echo "Sent message to $name <br>";

        sleep(1);
    } 
    catch (TwilioException $e) {
        die( $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this. Can you plz give me an example? Also i thought that i should se the success echo one by one in the loop.. but when the page fails.. and the loop stop i havent seen a single one success text. why is this?

Comment: Are you echoing the success messages to an HTML page?

Comment: The script as shown in my question is in a php file. I had the echo working before i used the try-catch function to sort out bad nr´s.

Comment: So, you don't see the success messages because your php file is building up the HTML to send back to the browser. However, when you hit the error you call for the process to `die` which replaces the HTML you were building up with an error page.

Comment: I see. I got this code from another answer where i was asking for a way to keep sending sms after a bad/not working number.  How should i do this instead and how to implement a delay?

Comment: You implement a delay using `sleep`. See my updated answer.

Comment: can i just use echo instead of die?

Comment: You could, yes.

Comment: Perfect i will try this.. maby tomorrow.. so i don´t flood the ones who get´s the SMS ;D